# Marginal Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, marginal-distribution, integral

I have a confusion over an integral involving a multivariate and a univariate Gaussian.
We know that in the case of two multivariate Gaussians the following is true:
$$
\int \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{S})
\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{b}|\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{C}) \mathbf{db} =  \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{m}, \mathbf{S} + \mathbf{C})
$$

Could somebody please tell me what the integral evaluates to in the following case where $b$ is now a scalar:
$$
\int \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + b\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{S})
\mathcal{N}(b|m, c^2) db
$$

where

- $\mathbf{1}$ is a column of ones of the same dimension as $\mathbf{y}$
- $\mathcal{N}(b|m, c^2)$ is the univariate Gaussian distribution with mean $m$ and standard devation of $c$.

Comment: Can you give a reference for the formula you know? The notation in these integrals is not quite standard, so they are not clear to me immediately.

Comment: Thanks. One reference is Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, equations 2.113 - 2.115.

Comment: Also here is the link to the book: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf

Comment: The first equation in the post might need an analog of the $A\Lambda^{-1}A^T$ in Bishop’s 2.115.

Comment: My guess is not, as it is the b that is integrated out and not the x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution$$\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{b}|\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{C})$$
simplifies into the distribution$$\mathcal{N}({b}|{m}, {c^2})$$
over the diagonal when
$$\mathbf{m}={m}\boldsymbol{1}\quad \text{and}\quad \mathbf{C}=c^2\boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{1}^\top$$

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed what I have been using, but it was based more on intuition which I tend to be wary of